# Why does "truffle migrate" to Rinkeby results two transactions per contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, rinkeby

I ran `truffle migrate -f 2 --network rinkeby`. Then, I navigated to https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/[ADDRESS_OF_DEPLOYER]

And I got two TXs:

[image]

The second TX is clear since `To` equals to "Contract Creation". Now, what is the first TX? The `From` is the same as the second TX, however, the `To` is another address (0xb52078acf139....).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a migration step with Truffle, it records in the `Migrations` contract which step it just completed.

So even for the [initial migration](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#initial-migration), when it runs, the content of `migrations/1_initial_migration.js`, it will deploy the `Migrations` contract and right away call `setCompleted(1)` on it.

If you have another file `2_deploy_mine.js`, it will do as you ask and at the end, call `setCompleted(2)` on the `Migrations` contract.

That's what this *extra* tx is.